# Где хранятся файлы Media Library в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно, вопрос касается и файлов на сервере, и базы данных - где хранятся файлы Media Library в Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы хранятся в папках вида /wp-content/uploads/2016/10 (по месяцам)

Информация о них - в базе.
В таблице wp_posts в записи типа attachment (post_type=atachment) хранится имя и основная информация о файле.
В таблице wp_postmeta в записях с post_id = номеру поста в wp_posts хранятся путь к файлу и метаданные.

Comment: Подскажите, а что такое guid, вроде: http://yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru/1506273_331567360319439_814738258_o-jpg-18/

Comment: И что значит, если папки "uploads" нет?

Comment: Буду очень признателен!

Comment: guid - это некое начальное значение ссылки на объект. WordPress сохраняет его, даже если сайт переехал на новый адрес. Это делается для отслеживания pingback и trackback. В целом, можно игнорировать этот столбец.

Comment: что значит - нет папки uploads? Тогда WP установлен неправильно или поврежден.